# Eclipse - Change the background color of selected file in the 'View' window

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse Indigo - I have 'Link with Editor' option enabled in my 'Package Explorer' view.

Whenever I select a file in the editor, that particular file is highlighted on my Package Explorer view. I would like to change the background color of that highlighted file in the view. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You might be able to do something with the GTK colour settings http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity

Comment: @BullfrogBlues Thanks. I tried in xp, 'Registory Editor' [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors]. In fact, I couldn't exactly figure out the name for my need. (ie) When I click the file in Package Explorer, that file is highlighted with blue color, but when i put focus on the editor, the file on package explorer gets gray color. Not sure if this is called 'InactiveTitle' or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As illustrated by [bug 74769](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=74769), the background color selection of the tree used by the Package explorer is set by the system color preferences, not by an Eclipse preference.
Same story [for fonts](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=49548).